# The best way to write Javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not new to web dev but I was just wondering if you guys have some advice for me to improve:

Always when I write js or jQuery I write all the code like this in the `<head>` on my page:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

   //All my functions and animations goes here…

});
</script>
```

Now, when I look around the web I see that most people have their functions and animations in a separate ".js"-file. And they often create classes aswell.

How does that work? What is the advantage of creating classes and have your functions in a separate file?

Thanks, VG

Comment: Great question and one that I've been meaning to ask for weeks now. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Advantages of putting your javascript into a separate file:

1. **Reuse on multiple pages** - You can more easily reuse the same javascript functions on multiple pages without having multiple separate copies of the code.
2. **More efficient caching** - The browser can much more efficiently cache your javascript which can lead to faster page load times.  When using an external JS file, it can be loaded upon first use and then retrieved from the browser cache for all subsequent page loads that use that same JS file.
3. **Separation of code from HTML** - You get better separation of the different types of content on the page.  The visual designer can work on the HTML while the software developer can work on the javascript and they are not working in the exactly same file.

Note: for performance reasons, you don't want to have a lot of small, separate external JS files as it takes longer to load lots of small JS files than it does one larger JS file.

### Structuring code into classes/objects can have the following advantages:

1. **Organization** - It forces the developer to organize their code into blocks of functionality where you have an object with a given set of methods and properties.  For anything other than a trivial project, this is a much cleaner way or organizing things than just a big list of javascript functions.
2. **Encapsulation** - Object oriented design causes you to put data into objects where it's much clearer who owns the data, who modifies the data, what it's lifetime is and what methods exist to modify the data.  In addition, some data can be encapsulated inside the object so it can only be modified via the desired methods (not mucked with directly).
3. **Testing** - it can be much easier to write test suites for code organized into objects, methods and properties.
4. **Self documenting** - Code organized into objects, methods and properties is general much more self-documenting that a long list of procedures.
5. **Modularity** - It is typically easier to break object-oriented code into reusable modules than code that is not organized this way.
6. **Extensibility** - A good object oriented design can be much easier to extend and enhance through things like sub-classing and method overrides than straight procedural code.
7. **Maintainability** - For all the above reasons, good object oriented code can be easier to maintain.

FYI, many of the advantages of object oriented thinking and design can be found without using literal classes (which javascript doesn't even really have).  It's more a matter of how you design and implement your code than it is a particular language syntax feature.  For example, you can have an object oriented design in plain C which has no specific language concept of a class or object.  In javascript lots of language elements are objects with extensible properties and methods so it's even easier to do object oriented design in javascript (in fact, it's hard to avoid doing it) because there are already objects all around you (the window object, all the DOM objects, etc...).

Comment: The best way to write javascript is using typescript =)

Answer (score 3):

The advantage of putting your javascript code in separate files is that you no longer mix markup (which is what HTML is) and scripting. You have a clear separation of concerns. Same stands for CSS. Styling goes into separate files. As a result your markup becomes smaller. The javascript being static, client browsers are caching all those external static files. So they don't need to fetch it everytime a request is made. This improves the performance of your applications because there is less data to send over the wire. Only the markup that changes from page to page is retrieved from the server.

As far as organizing your scripts into classes and functions, that's for better readability and reusability. When you are working on large projects with lots of javascript it is better if you could split it into separate modules so that those modules could be easier to maintain by different developers on the team.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! But if I have something that is clickable om my site, example: $(".button").click(function() { }); and I write that in a separate .js file then it won't work because ".button" does not exist in the .js file? Do you know what I mean?

Comment: @ViktorGidlöf, `.button` is a jquery class selector. It selects an element in the DOM with `class="button"`. It is not an element that you put in your javascript. It is part of the markup. Also if the element doesn't exist in your markup the jQuery selector won't return any elements and nothing will happen - the click handler won't be attached.

Answer (score 1):

Splitting up your classes and what not into separate files makes the more maintainable and more reuseable for other projects.  It just keeps things organized.

Beware though... you don't want to have a ton of files the client has to go download!  Often times, something will be running server-side to assemble all of the relevant files into one download.  PHP can do this for you easily.

Comment: There is a similar offering for .NET developers called Cassette. http://getcassette.net/ - Another option is QuishIt.

Answer (score 0):

quite a lot of difference and better practice.  But for example you whant that jquery function to be in another file you could write the code once. Also it will increase the speed of your website with having only to load the content once.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, implementing js Object classes helps avoid namespace collision with variable & function names... all in all, in my opinion a good practice to get into.